# Improving the quality of reduced website screenshots in GIMP

Tags: gimp

I'm trying to improve the quality of reduced screenshots of websites in GIMP.

This is waht I do:

1. Scale the image using the Sinc interpolation.
2. Apply some blur (0.5)

This is the result:

[image]

I would like to know if the quality of my result is closer to this one:

[image]

If not, what other techniques do you recommend to improve the screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinc is broken.

Try this:

1. Figure out ratio between source image and final image (e.g. 1200px width to become 600px give you 2
2. Apply Gaussian blur with that value
3. Scale down with linear interpolation
4. Apply sharpening to your liking